# Xcode 10 how to add new element in separate window

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode10

I'm using XCode 10.1 and it seems they yet again changed things nobody asked for, and now I can only add new elements to a storyboard via a circular menu on top.

Fine, however when I open the storyboard in a new window, this menu is not showing, and they removed the old way to add new UI elements. So any way to use the new menu in a separate window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold down the Option key when clicking the Library button in the project window toolbar, the object library will stay open in a separate window, and you can access the user interface elements from your storyboard opened in a new window.

See matt's answer to the following question for more details:

[Where did the Object Library go in Xcode 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962797/where-did-the-object-library-go-in-xcode-10)