# How to add a UIImageView to a storyboard in Xcode 12?

Tags: xcode

Very basic question: How do I add a UIImageView to a storyboard in Xcode 12? I [have an existing project](https://github.com/jeradesign/GameControllerTest) and I want to add images to it. I'm new to Xcode.

I gather I need to use  Interface Builder Xcode 12. [This tutorial for Xcode 10](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/adding-image-assets) shows how to add images to Images.xcassets but assumes I know how to add an UIImageView.

The tutorial shows a library of widgets displayed in the bottom right: [image: gif of adding image]

But I don't have that:

[image: my xcode]

At the end, it mentions:

> Media Library pop up opened by hitting the keys "command", "shift", and "m" at the same time Add image asset to launch screen Xcode 10

But that key combo does nothing for me.

Comment: [Where did the Object Library go in Xcode 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962797/where-did-the-object-library-go-in-xcode-10) is a related question, but things are moved again for Xcode 12. (The button to add is different, the Cmd-Shift-M command doesn't do anything anymore.) Howeever, there are some Xcode 11 answers on that page are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are three solutions:

- Command-Shift-L is the new shortcut to open the media library. [Seems like this changed in Xcode 11?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123079?answerId=383770022#383770022)
- The + icon shown in the screenshot.
- View > Show Library